# R columns as row values

Tags: r, join, datatable, row, multiple-columns

I tried different things. Like the gather function of the tdyr package... but I got no good results...

I have the following table:

```
year    Sudan   Africa

1964    5.586   13.087
1965    4.885   14.133
1966    4.233   14.343
```

and I would to have the data like this:

```
year   country   value

1964   Sudan     5.586
1964   Africa    13.087
1965   Sudan     4.885
1965   Africa    14.133
1966   Sudan     4.233
1966   Africa    14.343
```

This is only a subset of the data. I have all countries of the world and values from 1964 - 2013.

thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
 pivot_longer(df1, cols = -year, names_to = 'country')
```